# Email not arriving to my server, with address root@<IP>

Tags: email, postfix

I have a standard Debian running with IP 203.0.113.2, with Postfix installed (default config).

I tried sending an email, with a Gmail address, to `root@203.0.113.2`.

When doing

```
$ mail
```

I don't see this email.

**How to make my server accept emails sent to `root@203.0.113.2` from outside?**

PS: I had a response from Gmail: `Bad recipient address syntax`.

PS2: I know it's better to have a domain name, but this is just for a sandbox server

Comment: Isn't the correct format: `user@[127.0.0.1]`??

Comment: @mdpc I tried in Gmail sending to `root@[203.0.113.2]`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Bad recipient address syntax` response from Gmail indicates that the problem is not with your postfix server. Rather, Gmail expects a domain name and does not accept an IP address. The simplest solution is probably to set up a domain name, configure the MX record on the DNS to point to the Postfix server, and then configure postfix to accept emails for the domain.

Alternatively, you could set up a local SMTP server on the machine that you are using to send the test emails and then configure the MTA to send email through the local SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

RFC allow ip and domain names in email addresses but most servers will not accept this messages.

Exchange Server will return this error code:

```
501 5.1.3 Invalid address (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Postfix return this answer:

```
Remote Server returned '501 5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax'
```

You need valid second-level (domain.tld) or third-level (name.domain.tld) domain name with MX record on your DNS provider.